# Print a Pyramid using TCL

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am confused how to concat and repeat a character using PERL. Kindly help me out. I need to print a Pyramid using TCL. Below is my code.

Tcl

---

```
set height 10
set spaceChar " "
set pyramidChar ^

for {set i 1} {$i <= $height} {incr i} {
    set y "concat {$spaceChar *($height - $i)} {$pyramidChar * $i} "
    puts $y
}
```

PERL < Which works >

---

```
print "Please Enter Pyramind Height:";
my $height = <>; chomp($height); # strip of new lines

my $char='^';

for(my $i=1; $i<=$height; ++$i){
    print ' ' x ($height-$i) . $char x (2*$i-1), "\n";
```

Comment: I am confused how to concat and repeat a character using TCL* & not PERL.

Comment: Also, the code i entered are not properly formatted after i added the question. Kindly bare with me. IF you know a solution for the same, kindly help.

Comment: set height 10
set spaceChar " "
set pyramidChar ^

for {set i 1} {$i <= $height} {incr i} {
set y "concat {$spaceChar x ($height - $i)} {$pyramidChar x (2*$i - 1)} "
puts $y
}

Prints

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the fact that arithmetic has to be done with the `expr` command. Also, perl `.` => tcl `append` and perl `x` => tcl `string repeat`

The translation of your perl is

```
for {set i 1} {$i <= $height} {incr i} {
    puts [string cat [string repeat " " [expr {$height - $i}]] [string repeat $char [expr {$i*2-1}]]]
}
```

Although long lines of Tcl code can be quite hard to read with all the nested brackets. Perhaps:

```
for {set i 1} {$i <= $height} {incr i} {
    set indent [string repeat " " [expr {$height - $i}]]
    set tier [string repeat $char [expr {$i*2-1}]]
    puts "$indent$tier"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Glenn. I understand very well now. Have a great day.

Comment: For readers benefit and clarity. anything missing in append part...? Second code works fine.

set height 3
set char ^

for {set i 1} {$i <= $height} {incr i} {
    puts [append [string repeat " " [expr {$height - $i}]] [string repeat $char [expr {$i*2-1}]]]
}

It prints - (But not a pyramid. Space is not coming at the begining.)

^
^^^
^^^^^

Comment: `append` in the first example is missing a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

[concat](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/concat.htm) is a list operator, not a string operator.

The `x` operator in perl repeats a string.  You cannot translate that to a `*` in Tcl.  You need to use the [string repeat](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M41) command.

To concatenate characters in Tcl, simply put them next to each other, e.g.

```
set y "[string repeat { } 5][string repeat {^} 2]"
```

I am using quotes here for clarity -- they're not really necessary in this case.  Or use the [string cat](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M5) command.

```
set y [string cat [string repeat { } 5][string repeat {^} 2]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Brad, i clearly understand now. Logic works well. Resolved my doubt.